# Hide menu after click in betheme

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an overlay menu (Wordpress betheme)
After I click on a menu item it doesn't close automatically.

Can anybody help to close the menu after the click?

```js
/* ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * Menu | Overlay
 * --------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

$('.overlay-menu-toggle').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).toggleClass('focus');
  $('#Overlay').stop(true, true).fadeToggle(500);

  var menuH = $('#Overlay nav').height() / 2;
  $('#Overlay nav').css('margin-top', '-' + menuH + 'px');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="Overlay">
  <nav id="overlay-menu">
    <ul id="menu-felso-menu" class="menu overlay-menu">
      <li id="menu-item-112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-112"><a href="gyordetailing.hu/#detailing">Miért mi?</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div><a class="overlay-menu-toggle" href="#"><i class="open icon-menu-fine"></i>TOGGLE</a>
```

Comment: Hey Daniel. Thanks for including the JavaScript, however without the associated HTML, i'm not sure it will be all that helpful to us. Any chance you can add a minimal portion of HTML that replicates the issue you're having?

Comment: Dear Tyler!
<div id="Overlay"><nav id="overlay-menu"><ul id="menu-felso-menu" class="menu overlay-menu"><li id="menu-item-112" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item current_page_item menu-item-home menu-item-112"><a href="https://gyordetailing.hu/#detailing">Miért mi?</a></li>
</ul></nav></div><a class="overlay-menu-toggle" href="#"><i class="open icon-menu-fine"></i><i class="close icon-cancel-fine"></i></a>

Comment: Thanks Daniel. As you can tell, it's very difficult to make sense of HTML inside of comments - it gets all jumbled together. Instead, you can click the **Edit** button underneath your post, click the **Edit Snippet** link underneath your code snippet, and add this HTML to it. Also, make sure on the left side, you choose jQuery from the dropdown. **EDIT:** I've made the  changes for you, but will leave these instructions here so you can know them for next time :)

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like your code works just fine... Your issue is likely somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me with the Side Slide menu. Just put the code in the JS window in the "Theme Options" and adapt the menu IDs to your code. Betheme does nothing else than slide in and out the mobile menu (e.g. right: -250px;), slide the whole body to the left (e.g. left: -125px;) and display a dark "body_overlay" when the menu is active. I have links with #anker and links for normal subpages so I addressed each #anker separately (#menu-item-155).
The class .icon-menu-fine is from the burger menu to get things working again after closing the menu through JS.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {

$('#menu-item-155 a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $(this).toggleClass('focus');
  $('#Side_slide').stop(true, true).fadeToggle(500);

  $('#Side_slide').css('right', '-250px');
  $('body').css('left', '0px');
  $('#body_overlay').css('display', 'none');
});


$('.icon-menu-fine').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#Side_slide').css('right', '0px');
  $('body').css('left', '-125px');
  $('#body_overlay').css('display', 'block');
  $('#Side_slide').css('display', 'block');
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just copied part of BeTheme code, that closes menu with a little modifications.

Just put this code in the JS window in the "Theme Options" > "Custom CSS & JS":

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  /* Close Side Menu on item click */
  $('#Side_slide .menu-item a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    /* globals jQuery, mfn */
    var mobileInitW = (mfn.mobileInit) ? mfn.mobileInit : 1240
    var slide = $('#Side_slide')
    var overlay = $('#body_overlay')
    var ssMobileInitW = mobileInitW
    var pos = slide.hasClass('left') ? 'left' : 'right'
    var shiftSlide = -slide.data('width')
    var shiftBody = shiftSlide / 2
    var duration = 300

    if (pos === 'left') {
      slide.animate({ 'left': shiftSlide }, duration)
      $('body').animate({ 'right': 0 }, duration)
    } else {
      slide.animate({ 'right': shiftSlide }, duration)
      $('body').animate({ 'left': 0 }, duration)
    }

    overlay.fadeOut(300)

    // if page contains revolution slider, trigger resize
    if ($('.rev_slider').length) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $(window).trigger('resize')
      }, 300)
    }

  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me.  It seems the action button that is used will go to the set anchor on the page but wouldn't close the slide menu.  Really weird behavior.  Not sure ever why you would like that effect, especially when a dark overlay is placed over the page.

It seemed for in my case I needed to remove all the dollar signs.  Manuel had the solution just had to change things because of the $'s

Of course, you will see I had to adjust the initial tag that I wanted to be detected for the closing of the slider.

```html
jQuery(document).ready(function()
 {
   jQuery('a.action_button.scroll').click(function(e)  /* Change this line with the ones below for different menu behaviours*/
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery(this).toggleClass('focus');
      jQuery('#Side_slide').stop(true, true).fadeToggle(500);
      jQuery('#Side_slide').css('right', '-250px');
      jQuery('body').css('left', '0px');
      jQuery('#body_overlay').css('display', 'none');
    });
   jQuery('.icon-menu-fine').click(function(e)
    {
      e.preventDefault();
      jQuery('#Side_slide').css('right', '0px');
      jQuery('body').css('left', '0px');
      jQuery('#body_overlay').css('display', 'block');
      jQuery('#Side_slide').css('display', 'block');
    });
 });
```

Really sweet stuff. It was super sweet seeing the menu close finally on click.

Of course, I have since adjusted it so that if any menu element is clicked/touched on then the slide menu will disappear with the below adjustment to the above code.

```html
jQuery('ul#menu-main-menu-1').click(function(e)
```

I found the most pleasing behavior was to use this one though as it will trap any click on the menu and close it.

```html
jQuery('div#Side_slide').click(function(e)
```

btw: this code is inserted into the "Theme Options --> Custom CSS & JS --> JS